# jQuery .slideToggle() function isnt working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have found some jQuery codes for show content with slide effect, but none of them works.

the Javasccript code:

```
 $('#clickme').click(function() {
        $('#pic').slideToggle('slow', function() {
        });
    });
```

the HTML:

```
<div id="clickme">
        click here</div>
    <img id="pic" src="Img/Gallery/123.jpg" />
```

When i click the "click me" div, nothing happens. I have also tried this :

```
$("div").click(function () {
  $(this).hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
});
```

But again, nothing happens. What is the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: What is in your `console`? Any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways that it works:

1) Add the following code in the header

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("div").click(function () {
$('#pic').slideToggle('slow', function() {
    });
});
});
```

2) Place your code **after** your last div!

And obviously you have to include a jquery file!
For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have tried all what you said, I've already wrote the "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js", tried all your versions, tired to put it on- onload function, but still it dosent works

Comment: I have no idea why, suddenly it works, i didnt change anything from yesterday but whatever. 
Oh and how can i makr it slide from the side?

Comment: When you cahnge something on  your site, you should reload it with Right click -> Reload! Else it will sometimes reload the site from the cache! And this could help you if you want to slide it from the side: [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: I think you didnt usderstand me, right now when I click the "click me" to hide the picture, its sliding from the bottom to the top and disappear. i wnat it to slide from the right or the left

Comment: I think it works with the animate function: `$(document).ready(function () {
$("div").click(function () {
$('#pic').animate({
    width: "0%",
 height: $('#pic').height(),
    marginLeft: "0px"
  }, 1500 );
});
});`

Comment: How can i l do like in Microsofts site :http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx
I mean the picture slides to the side but bot like you did

Answer (score 1):

Put your code in

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    // Your code here    
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

you shlould load jQuery by adding this line at the `head`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to change your code to this:

```
   $("div").on("click", function () {
        $(this).hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CT3qX/) to see the working example. ) Btw, it's not necessary to pass the empty function to slideToggle, I suppose.

I guess the only difference is that you try to run your javascript not as `onload` function; it doesn't find any 'clickme' elements, that's why event handler function is not called.